# c#: Check which project is calling class library

Tags: c#

I have two projects which is calling a Class Library. Can i in my Class Library check which project is calling the Library?

Comment: May I ask - what design problem are you trying to solve? Reflection is never the right answer...

Comment: @Kobi: While I agree with you that Reflection may not be the answer to this problem, in general there are many problems that can be solved either only with Reflection, or with Reflection being easier. I have at least two applications here that rely on Reflection because there would be no other way. So I disagree with Reflection *never* being the right answer.

Comment: @Kobi, Reflection can and has been abused, but it is very much the "Right" answer to a bunch of problems.  If anything I see it popping up more and more commonly.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737/use-cases-for-reflection for some ideas on where it is very useful.

Comment: Sounds like a design problem to me. Class library should not really care who calls it, much like a button shouldn't care who (if anyone at all) will handle its Click event. You can, on the other hand, explicitly pass an identifier **from** your calling assembly, but the first question to ask is - why you are actually doing this?

Comment: I'm here over an year, and I keep reminding myself - "almost never make generalizations".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm...that doesn't sound good to me. What you're trying to achieve is to create a dependency from your class-library -> project which should instead be project -> class library dependency.

From my point this is "not" achievable and if so just hardly and is not considered good practice. A good class library should be of general purpose and should not change behavior depending on its caller.

(Maybe you could describe in more detail the nature of your problem, so I could help you better and find a better solution)

Comment: While it's true that a good class library should be of general purpose, this is certainly not true if the class library is a part of the application and is not intended to be used elsewhere. On the other hand, even such a library should change behaviour only *when given different parameters*.

Comment: I agree. When speaking about class library I think however always about a general purpose, re-usable construct. Given the fact that he says that the library is accessed by 2 projects I assume it to be general purpose. A class library may depend on some configuration, but never behave differently by making decisions itself. The setting of the configuration should always come from outside.

Answer (score 2):

If that projects have different namespaces, you can use [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) to build your call stack:

```
public static void Main()
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
    foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackFrames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not store a unique value for each project in the App.Config file and then read this value from within your class library. Depending on what project (application) you are running it should pick up the correct application config. Or even just check the `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name()`

Comment: Isn't the executing assembly the one that contains the code that calls GetExecutingAssembly()? I.e. if you call it in your library assembly, you will get your library assembly - but there's still GetCallingAssembly, which is likely what you meant :)

Answer (score 1):

if what you are looking for is the main application assembly, then the correct call is Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName
just my 2¢

Answer (score 1):

Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() will give you a reference to the assembly that invoked the method in which you put that line of code.  I think this is exactly what you are asking but it is rare that a library should ever care about its caller so you may want to have a think about whether the approach is, indeed, correct.

```
// in Assembly 1
public class Assembly1Class
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        assembly2ClassInstance.SomeAPIMethod();
    }
}

// in Assembly 2 (the library)
public class Assembly2Class
{
    public void SomeAPIMethod()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after security (in some way), the [.NET Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28VS.71%29.aspx) may be what you want.