# Object reflection c#

Tags: c#

I want to generate the right object with one code line and not a switch case because always when a new device is added I have to add a new line.

Is it possible to do that in one line without switch case?

```
public static Device GetDevice(Device.enumDevice TypeOfDevice, string alias)
{
    // Create the Object with using reflection

    switch (TypeOfDevice)
    {
        case Device.enumDevice.A34411:
            return new A34411(string alias);
            break;
        case Device.enumDevice.N5744:
            return new N5744(string alias);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Where are you using reflection?

Comment: You could put a custom attribute on the classes and using reflection, enumerate all subclasses of the `Device` base class, looking for that attribute with the right value.

Comment: So your plan is to remove the use of enum too?

Comment: `return new A34411(string alias);`  this syntax is incorrect.  Remove the `string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflection in factory design patterns in Java or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768610/reflection-in-factory-design-patterns-in-java-or-c-sharp)

Comment: Also, the final `return null` is useless, because is unreachable. All possible paths end in one branch of the switch, and every branch returns or throws an Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the factory methods as delegates in a dictionary

```
private static Dictionary<Device.enumDevice, Func<string, Device>> _factoryDict =
    new Dictionary<Device.enumDevice, Func<string, Device>>{
        [Device.enumDevice.A34411] = (alias) => new A34411(alias),
        [Device.enumDevice.N5744] = (alias) => new N5744(alias),
    };

...

public static Device GetDevice(Device.enumDevice TypeOfDevice, string alias)
{
    if (_factoryDict.TryGetValue(TypeOfDevice, out var factory)) {
        return factory(alias);
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    // No retun statement here, as it would be unreachable because of the throw statement.
}
```

---

Or, using reflection:

```
const string deviceNameSpace = "MyName.MyProject.Devices.";

public static Device GetDevice(Device.enumDevice deviceType, string alias)
{
    string typeName = deviceNameSpace + deviceType.ToString();
    Type type = Type.GetType(typeName, throwOnError: true);
    return (Device)Activator.CreateInstance(type, alias);
}
```

Comment: second example incorrect. Type.GetType require "namespace.class" in the simplest case, but better to use full  AssemblyQualifiedName.

Comment: @arndtdv: You are right. If the classes are in the same assembly, you can omit  AssemblyQualifiedName.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant approach would be to use Dependency Injection with "Named Type Registrations"

Answer (score 1):

Fast, but not quite a complete example:

```
public abstract class Device
{
    protected Device(string alias)
    {
        Alias = alias;
    }
    public string Alias { get; }
}

public class A1 : Device
{
    public A1(string alias) : base(alias) { }
}

public class A2 : Device
{
    public A2(string alias) : base(alias) { }
}

class DeviceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DeviceAttribute(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public Type Type { get; }
}

public enum DeviceEnum
{
    [Device(typeof(A1))]
    A1,
    [Device(typeof(A2))]
    A2
}

public static class DeviceEnumExtension
{
    public static Device GetInstance(this DeviceEnum obj, string alias)
    {
        var member = typeof(DeviceEnum).GetMember(obj.ToString());

        if (member[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DeviceAttribute), false)[0] is DeviceAttribute deviceAttr)
        {
            var ctor = deviceAttr.Type.GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(string)});
            return ctor.Invoke(new object[] {alias}) as Device;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var a1 = DeviceEnum.A1;
        var a2 = DeviceEnum.A2;

        // Act
        var instanceA1 = a1.GetInstance("A1");
        var instanceA2 = a2.GetInstance("A2");

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(typeof(A1), instanceA1.GetType());
        Assert.Equal(typeof(A2), instanceA2.GetType());
        Assert.Equal("A1", instanceA1.Alias);
        Assert.Equal("A2", instanceA2.Alias);
    }
}
```